# Starting TypeScript program from Visual Studio Code: "Cannot launch program 'hw.ts' because corresponding JavaScript cannot be found."

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have `hw.ts` file with this content:

```
function greeter(x: string) {
    return "Hello" + x;
}

let u = "John";
document.body.innerHTML = greeter(u);
```

I select `Start without debugging` and VSCode says:

```
Cannot launch program 'hw.ts' because corresponding JavaScript cannot be found.
```

OK so I compile file from the commandline:

```
tsc hw.ts
```

Now I *do* have `hw.js` in the same folder.

So again I select `Start without debugging` and VSCode again says `Cannot launch program 'hw.ts' because corresponding JavaScript cannot be found.`.

Is there any way to compile & run TypeScript program from VSCode? What am I missing?

(I do have `node` in my `PATH`, it should be visible to VSCode)

Comment: Follow this official guide: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-tutorial

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me as soon as I changed

```
  "outFiles": [
    "./dist/**/*.js"
  ],
```

to

```
  "outFiles": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have set the correct path to your `*.js` files in the `launch.json`. This can be done by defining the `outFiles` option. Furthermore, to enable debugging `*.ts` files you can set `sourceMaps` to `true`. This tells vscode that it should try to map the compiled `*.js` files to the corresponding `*.ts` files.
Example:

```
"sourceMaps": true,
"outFiles": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/your/jsFiles/**/*.js"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your launch.json file replace

`"outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"]`

for

`"outFiles": ["${fileDirname}/**/*.js"]`

It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I solved it using the following steps:

### 1.Configure

Specify output directory and enable sourceMap in `tsconfig.json`

```
"outDir": "./out",  /* Specify .js output files. */
"sourceMap": true   /* Generate corresponding .map files. */
```

### 2.Build

Now Click Run Build Task (Shift + Command(Ctrl) + B) from the Terminal menu of the VS Code and type the following command and press enter:

```
tsc: watch - tsconfig.json
```

You need to Run Build Task once when you first open the project. This will start watching for code changes in the project.

### 3.Run

Now go to the Typescript program that you want to run (Make sure your program file `.ts` has the focus).

From the Run menu, click Run Without Debugging(Ctrl + F5).

You can see the output in the Debug Console.